# How to redirect HashRouter URLs to use BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm transitioning a project from using HashRouter to BrowserRouter, however there are some links in other sites and email campaigns that are linking to the site using the old HashRouter URLs. Is there a way to redirect those to not use the /# in the url?

For example if linked to 
    #/planet/mars
It should redirect to
   /planet/mars

I tried a Switch/Redirect shown below but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
<Switch>
 <Redirect from="/#/planet/:planet" to="/planet/:planet" />
 <Route
  path="/planet/:planet"
  exact
  component={PlanetPage} />
</Switch>
```